# Google Pie Chart not displaying Internet Explorer 8

Tags: php, internet-explorer-8, google-visualization

I'm using a Google Pie chart which displays as expected in Firefox but doesn't display in IE8 and gives the following error in the console:

```
SCRIPT5022: Every row given must be either null or an array. 
format+en,default,corechart.I.js, line 202 character 63
```

I'm using a Google Line Chart on another page and this displays fine.

Appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Please show us the code of your implementation. Greetings,
Frederick

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. Its because theres a trailing comma at the end of the last element of the array containing the data to populate the chart. Removing this comma gets rid of the error and the graph displays as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install "google chrome frame". I fixed this after installed this.

Open IE and click the following link.

[Link](http://www.google.com/chromeframe?quickenable=true)

Comment: This won't actually fix the problem, this is more of a workaround for sloppy programming...